# google calendar acces from Python

Tags: python, calendar

I newbe on this communauty

till nov 17, I used google calendar V2 to turn on or off my swiming pool pump

I'm trying to upgrade my python script to Google API V3 but I'm not sure to understand everything:

I'm using (no, trying to use) following code get on internet :

```
# Inspired from 'Raspberry Pi as a Google Calender Alarm Clock'
# http://www.esologic.com/?p=634

from datetime import datetime
import logging, os, platform, re, time

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

from config import *


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Alarm():
system = platform.system().lower()
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                               redirect_uri='http://localhost:8080/')

storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
    credentials = run(flow, storage)

# Google Calendar service connection
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http, developerKey=API_KEY)

def check_credentials(self):
    if self.credentials is None or self.credentials.invalid == True:
        credentials = run(self.flow, self.storage)

def calendar_event_query(self):
    self.check_credentials()
    today = datetime.today()
    events = self.service.events().list(singleEvents=True, calendarId=CALENDAR_ID).execute()

    for i, event in enumerate(events['items']):
        name = event['summary'].lower()
        start = event['start']['dateTime'][:-9]
        description = event.get('description', '')
        repeat = True if description.lower() == 'repeat' else False
        now = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

        if start >= now:
            logger.debug('Event #%s, Name: %s, Start: %s', i, name, start)

            if start == now:
                if name.startswith('say'):
                    name = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\']', '', name)
                    command = '{0} "{1}"'.format('say' if system == 'darwin' else 'espeak -      ven+m2', name[4:])
                    logger.info('Event starting. Announcing \'%s\'...', name[4:])
                else:
                    mp3_files = os.listdir(MP3_FOLDER)
                    mp3_name = name.replace(' ', '_') + '.mp3'
                    mp3_name = mp3_name if mp3_name in mp3_files else 'default.mp3'
                    command = 'mpg123 \'{}/{}\''.format(MP3_FOLDER, mp3_name)
                    logger.info('Event %s starting. Playing mp3 file %s...', name, mp3_name)
                os.system(command)
                if repeat == False:
                    time.sleep(60)

def poll(self):
    logger.info('Polling calendar for events...')
    self.calendar_event_query()


while True:
    a = Alarm()
    a.poll()
    time.sleep(FREQUENCY_CHECK)
```

Of course, I created client ID and key ID on google consele

But, when I run my script, It's not working and I get a webpage on my raspberry with an error 400 : rederict_URI mismatch

An idea?